# What are reasons for downloading into temporary file and then copying?

Tags: android, download

I have the legacy code (Android code, if matters) to download file from the web URL. The code creates the temporary file as a target, downloads the content there using the Android DownloadManager and (at receiving the download complete notification) copies the downloaded content to the actual destination, as specified by the content disposition.

Is there any rationale for this approach? Which potential problems the author tried to solve? Or is this just an over-engineered code and I can replace this with download into the intended final destination?

Comment: `to the actual destination, as specified by the content disposition.`. Can you give an example of how such line would look like? And if the downloadmanager would download the file then how would the app know the content disposition? Strange.

Comment: `The code creates the temporary file as a target, downloads the content there using the Android DownloadManager`. Strange code. It should not create a temporary file at all as the downloadmanager would create that temporary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any rationale for this approach?

If the temporary file is on external storage, and the final destination is on internal storage, the workaround is because AFAIK `DownloadManager` does not support `content` `Uri` values as the destination location for a download. Bear in mind that `DownloadManager` does the downloading in a separate process, and so it does not have access to your app's internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the reason to use a temporary file is to not to overwrite the actual file before the download is completely finished (file move is atomic operation). This way you don't end up reading incomplete data or the result of a failed download when you load the actual file somewhere.